# feature deriveマクロは関数や構造体の上にしかつけれないのでしょうか？

Tags: rust

[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/kvevl0uio3c62x)でも同じ質問をさせていただきましたが、回答を得れていないためこちらでも質問させていただきます！

## 追記

以下の情報はすべてこのリポジトリに関するお話を抽象化したものです。
https://github.com/s3pt3mb3r/toy-arms
このリポジトリには `internal` と `external` と名のついたフォルダーと、featureがあります。
それぞれのフォルダー内のファイルに記述されたpublic関数は、対応するfeatureがonの場合でないと、外部のライブラリ使用者からuseできないようにしたいです！

## 背景、やりたいこと

自分のlibプロジェクトのsrc配下のファイルを、機能カテゴリごとにフォルダわけしたいなと思いたちました。
AとBのフォルダがあったとして、理想としては、ライブラリの使用者側で`features = ["A"]`を指定した場合は

```rust
use LIBRARY_NAME::A::FUNCTION_NAME;
// use LIBRARY_NAME::B::FUNCTION_NAME などはできないようにする
```

という感じで指定する形にしたいです。

現在ファイル構造は以下のようになっています。

```
src -- lib.rs
    |-- A
          |-- mod.rs
          |-- A.rs
    |-- B
          |-- mod.rs
          |-- B.rs
```

`src/lib.rs`は以下のようになっています。

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "A")]
pub mod A;

#[cfg(feature = "B")]
pub mod B;
```

`A/mod.rs`は以下のようになっています。

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "A")]
pub mod A;
pub use A::*;
```

`B/mod.rs`も、Aと同じように以下のようになっています。

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "B")]
pub mod B;
pub use B::*;
```

## 問題

ただこれだと、現状使用者側から、`features = ["A"]`と指定しても

```rust
use LIBRARY_NAME::B::FUNCTION_NAME;
```

がなぜか使えるようになっています。
関数や構造体の上に逐次`#[cfg(feature = "A")]`などとアノテートしていけばいいのはわかるのですが、もっと楽な方法はありませんか？

Comment: 再現できませんでした。
mod.rsやlib.rsの内容はこれで全部でしょうか？

Comment: あるいはCargo.tomlでのfeaturesの定義が誤っているかもしれません

Comment: 返信遅くなりすみません！！ このリンクは自分のリポジトリなのですが、上記の説明はこれを基にしています。 いろいろ試行錯誤を重ねたため、lib.rsや各mod.rsの中身が現在は若干違うかもしれませんが、改めて説明します。このリポジトリにはsrc配下に`internal`と`external`のモジュール(フォルダー)があり、さらに`internal`と`external`というfeatureもあります。
これを外部から使う際に、`internal`や`external`フォルダの中の関数は、`internal`や`external`それぞれ対応するfeatureを指定していないと使えないようにしたいです。

Comment: リンクが貼られていないようです。ご確認ください

Comment: 誠に申し訳ありません！！
https://github.com/s3pt3mb3r/toy-arms
こちらです！><

Comment: 見てみましたが、そもそも現状では internal がオフのときに以下の行のせいでコンパイルが通らないようです

https://github.com/s3pt3mb3r/toy-arms/blob/4d788fe7c9ac93b3df8e2f4f26b5da0395a85226/src/lib.rs#L19

Comment: 僕の環境ではコンパイルできます。今のgithubのコードはcrates.ioに上がっていないため、git cloneしてからpath=で指定するか、git = "https://github.com/s3pt3mb3r/toy_arms" として最新版を使っていただきたいです。example/external.rsは普通にコンパイルが通ることを確認しています。

Comment: Windowsの環境を用意してやってみましたが、やはり `--no-default-features` で internalを無効にするとビルドが通りません

Comment: あれ、そもそもその引数を知りませんでしたすみません！！後で見てみます

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます。`--no-default-features`を付けないと、デフォルトのfeatureが無効にならないことに気づいていませんでした！！

Answer (score 1):

pappyさんのコメントを発端として解決しました。
`--no-default-features` フラッグもしくはdependencies内に`default-features=false`を付けてデフォルトのfeatureを無効にすることで使えなくなることが確認できました。